# How write sort with unknown argument. Cant iterate with void*/

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

In this `void* ic = b + j * sz;` and this `void* jc = ic - sz;` lines ide writing that expression must be a pointer to a complete type. I need to wright function which can sort everything so i use void*. I don't now how to iterate with void*. How get access to elements `void* base`like array.

**UPD**
pcharToInt is wrong. At fist i cast `void*` to `char*` and
turned out  heart symbols. Than i tried to work with `void*`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int (*CFT) (const void*, const void*);

int pcharToInt(char* a);
int cmp1(const void* a, const void* b);
void insort(void* base, size_t n, size_t sz, CFT cmp);

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 9, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 4 };
    void* a = arr;
    char* b = static_cast<char*>(a);
    return 0;
}

int pcharToInt(char* a) {
    int b = 0;
    char* tmp = a;
    while (*a) {
        b *= 10;
        b += (*a++ - '0');
    }
    a = tmp;
    return b;
}

int cmp1(const void* a, const void* b) {
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    n1 = pcharToInt((char*)a);
    n2 = pcharToInt((char*)b);
    if (n1 > n2) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void insort(void* base, size_t n, size_t sz, CFT cmp) {
    void* b = base;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            void* ic = b + j * sz;
            void* jc = ic - sz;
            if (cmp1(jc, ic)) {
                for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++) {
                    char tmp = jc[k];
                    jc[k] = ic[k];
                    ic[k] = tmp;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD2 Its old code vitch char**

```
char* b = static_cast<char*> (base);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            char* ic = b + j * sz;
            char* jc = ic - sz;
            if (cmp1(jc, ic)) {
                for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++) {
                    char tmp = jc[k];
                    jc[k] = ic[k];
                    ic[k] = tmp;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

**UPD3**
Trouble in line where I cast `void*` to `char*`. In result where are not right symbols.  It must be numbers in example code.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just use `std::sort` on something like a `std::vector`?

Comment: cast `void*` to `char*` or `unsigned char*` to increment/decrement it

Comment: Im learning how to write sorting algorithms.

Comment: C or C++? These are distinct languages.

Comment: In the `pcharToInt` function, what is the `tmp` variable for? You never modify the contents that `a` is pointing to, only the *local* variable `a`. Furthermore, why not use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)?

Comment: Mestkon, i tried to do this, but when i cast to `char*` incomprehensible characters are obtained.

Comment: One major problem is that you have an array of *integers*, but your comparison function treats it as an array of *strings*. And the casting in the `main` function tries to convert the array into an actual string (`char*`), and not an array of strings.

Comment: You ***can't*** sort things if you don't know what they are, which is why you're having problems.  A pointer only points to the beginning of any object.  You **must** know how big is it and what the bytes that compose it mean so you can compare objects and sort them.

Comment: pcharToInt is wrong. i tried cast `void*` to `char*`

Comment: sz its size of object

Comment: its c++ language

Comment: *sz its size of object*  That's not enough to properly sort.  The string literal "0123456" is 8 bytes long, as is a `uint64_t`.  Yet the sorting of those two types is different.  Imagine a `struct` with padding of indeterminate (and therefore irrelevant) content.

Comment: The `std::sort` is written to sort things without knowing the specific type being sorted.  Your algorithm should use that for inspiration on how to separate the sorting algorithm from the thing being sorted.  Using `void*` and hail mary casting is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you don't throw away type information.

Instead of

```
typedef int (*CFT) (const void*, const void*);
void insort(void* base, size_t n, size_t sz, CFT cmp);
int cmp1(const void* a, const void* b);
```

You should be writing

```
template<typename T>
using CFT = bool(*)(const T *, const T *);

template<typename T>
void insort(T* base, size_t n, CFT<T> cmp) {
    for (T* i = base + 1; i < base + n; i++)
    {
        for (T* j = i; j > base; j--)
        {
            if (cmp(j, i)) {
                std::swap(*j, *i)
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

int cmp1(const int * a, const int * b)
{ 
    return *a > *b; 
}
```

Note that you ignore the first element, and the `break` seems suspicious. You generally need to move more than one element when you find something out of order.

A proper insertion sort ([adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627/2610810)) would be

```
template<typename T, typename Compare = std::less<>>
void insertion_sort(T* first, size_t n, Compare cmp = Compare{})
{
    for (T* it = first; it != first + n; ++it) {
        auto const insertion = std::upper_bound(first, it, *it, cmp);
        std::rotate(insertion, it, std::next(it)); 
        assert(std::is_sorted(first, std::next(it), cmp));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer well, because I just started learning c ++ and I don't understand the constructions that you used, but you wrote something about `break` and in fact the mistake was in it, it had to be written in the `else` block. I also don't understand English well, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to mimic the operation of `qsort()` from the C standard library, the comparison function needs to be tailored to the type of the element being sorted and the sort order (ascending or descending). The comparison is called with pointer arguments of type `const void *` because `qsort()` is designed to work with arrays of any type and `void *` is the most general object pointer type.

For the specific case of comparing `int` elements, the `const void *` arguments should be converted to `const int *` and dereferenced to get the values of the `int` elements to be compared. The comparison function should return a negative, zero, or positive value to indicate the relative ordering of the two elements being compared.  For sorting elements of `int` type in ascending order, a suitable comparison function is the following:

```
int cmp1(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int aa = *(const int *)a; // convert pointer a and dereference
    int bb = *(const int *)b; // convert pointer b and defererence

    if (aa < bb)
        return -1;
    if (aa > bb)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

A comparison function for sorting `int` elements in *descending* order would be similar to the above but with the `-1` and `1` return values swapped.

Your `insort()` function requires a different return value from the comparison function, returning 0 instead of a negative value.  For compatibility with your `insort()` function, the function needs to be modified as follows:

```
int cmp1(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int aa = *(const int *)a; // convert pointer a and dereference
    int bb = *(const int *)b; // convert pointer b and defererence

    return (aa > bb);
}
```

---

For standard C (and C++?), pointer arithmetic on `void *` is not allowed because pointer arithmetic is only allowed on pointers to *complete* object types, and `void` is an *incomplete* object type by definition. Some compilers such as GCC permit pointer arithmetic of `void *` as an extension to the C standard be treating it the same as `char *` as far as pointer arithmetic is concerned. Portable code should avoid pointer arithmetic on `void *`. Your `insort()` function can be modified as follows for portability:

```
void insort(void* base, size_t n, size_t sz, CFT cmp) {
    char* b = (char*)base;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            char* ic = b + j * sz;
            char* jc = ic - sz;
            if (cmp1((void*)jc, (void*)ic)) {
                for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++) {
                    char tmp = jc[k];
                    jc[k] = ic[k];
                    ic[k] = tmp;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `return aa > bb;` in `cmp1`?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I should do that.

Comment: thanks for the help, your answer helped me shorten and expose the code